# cannot pass by reference to thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, zeromq

I am trying to pass by reference to a thread, a variable defined as:

```
zmq::context_t context(1);
```

like this:

```
t[thread_nbr] = std::thread(worker_routine, (void *)&context, trained_images);
```

However, when I do I get the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1505:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void* (*(void*, std::vector<TrainedImage>))(void*, std::vector<TrainedImage>&)>’
   typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                         ^
/usr/include/c++/5/functional:1526:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void* (*(void*, std::vector<TrainedImage>))(void*, std::vector<TrainedImage>&)>’
     _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
```

If I try to do `std::ref()` with it, I get a deleted function error.

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: what is the signature of `worker_routine` ?

Comment: [Off Topic] You really should not need to cast anything to `void*` when working with `std::thread`.  It is designed to work with the type system.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Including the declaration (at least) of `worker_routine` and `trained_images`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be the `trained_images` argument which your thread-function takes as argument by reference. The problem with this is that the `std::thread` object can't really handle references (it *copies* the arguments to the thread function, and references can't be copied).

The solution is to use wrapper objects like [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) for references:

```
t[thread_nbr] = std::thread(worker_routine, &context, std::ref(trained_images));
```